# Using a Zener diode MOSFET gate voltage control circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, motor-controller, fet

I have a little problem with my simple project.

I want to control a  24V / 4A blower motor.

It works okay, but the MOSFET gets too hot.

I used a Zener diode to make the gate voltage above 12V, but it does not work. The gate voltage is 4.3V.

This is my circuit:

[image: Circuit]

here is my history.

1. I changed D2 -> 12V , 15V, 17V (but same)
2. Removed R4
3. Removed R3 / changed R3 100R ~ 2.2K
4. Changed R5 100K

[IRLR7843 datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlr7843pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566de53526d8)

Comment: D2 will prevent the gate voltage from rising above 12 volts - it will not pull the gate voltage up to 12 volts.  Q1 is an emitter follower so can only pull the gate voltage up to about 0.7 volts less than the PWM High voltage.

Comment: KimJiHoon - Hi, You posted an "answer", but it wasn't the answer to your original question. It seemed to be info about a failed solution attempt, so it was deleted, sorry. || Since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to it (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself & don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add more info / clarification, please [edit] the question. Or comment to respond to a minor point. || Please be careful not to *change* the original question, now that you have an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

> *it does not work. The gate voltage is 4.3V*

That's quite correct. Gate voltage will be about 4.3 volts in the circuit you implemented. This is because Q1 is an emitter follower and the source voltage will always be slightly less than the base voltage (1 diode drop in fact). You need to use Q1 in a common-emitter configuration if you want full gate voltage: -

[image]

Jack Creasey reminded me that the circuit I've shown (although the simplest) does invert the logic and, this needs fixing in the PWM signal i.e. zero equals motor on.

Comment: my mistake, that +BATT is 24V and, Q2's 1 (gate voltage) must more than 9v ?

Comment: @KimJiHoon yes I can read the 24 volts and I know the gate voltage needs to be higher. That's what my answer is about. Your proposed circuit will not achieve 9 volts.

Comment: Thank you, I will remove the R5 and change the resistor tomorrow.

Comment: You can leave R3 at 470 ohms if you wish. D3 doesn't need to be 9 amp rated by the way.

Comment: @Andyaka also remember that the PWM needs to be inverted form the original sketch.

Comment: @JackCreasey yes, thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Actually, the IRLR7843 https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLR7843-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566de53526d8 has a logic level gate that should be almost fully on at 4.3V. So perhaps the heating is from switching losses, especially if PWM frequency is high. Making a push-pull gate driver from an NPN and PNP will provide faster turn-on and turn-off transitions.

Comment: I changed circuit
1. removed R5
but same gate voltage(Q1's) is still 4.3V

2. changed D2 -> 12V zener
but still same 4.3v

Comment: @KimJiHoon You will need to do more than remove R5.  You need to disconnect the gate of M1 from the emitter of Q1 and then connect it to the collector of Q1.  R5 needs to be replaced by a wire.

Comment: @KimJiHoon [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)